# jQuery character count onkeyup showing 1 character when 0 left

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, slim-lang

I'm using jQuery to show characters remaining in a text input and it's working fine but when it gets to 0 characters remaining it is showing 1 even though it doesn't allow you to enter more. This is probably something obvious and simple, but it's stumping me today. Here is the code I'm using:

```
= form.text_field :name, { required: true, class: "#{'error' if @project.errors[:name].present?}", placeholder: '40 characters max', maxlength: 40, :onkeyup => "countCharname(this)" }
span id="charName" class="margin-left-5"             

    function countCharname(val) {
      var len = val.value.length;
      if (len >= 40) {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, 40);
      } else {
        $('#charName').text(40 - len);
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing it, my assumption is that when it reaches the max length, the input length is 40.  This means that the if statement `(len >= 40)` is true, so the else statement, which updates the `$('#charName')` with the remaining characters, doesn't get run.

Try changing the if statement to `(len > 40)`

Comment: That did it! I knew it'd be something simple like that. Thanks for the fresh eyes.